# How to change name of token on etherscan?

Tags: tokens

How do I update the name of my token SHNZ? Currently on etherscan, it's showing

Erc20 (SHNZ)
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7968ca1f368098784fc651277bfd29f610cf91f7#tokentxns

How do I update it so it displays with the token symbol: http://www.shizzlenizzle.com/SHNZ_28x28.png

to the left of the token name SHNZ

I already submitted the information and the icon at: https://etherscan.io/contactus

Comment: Hi. This isn't a duplicate. I already sent the information to https://etherscan.io/contactus though token icon isn't updated.

Comment: Hi there. Have you had a reply yet? Or do you mean they replied, but said they couldn't do it?

Comment: You mean the token icon, not the symbol. Anyways, that is done by Etherscan. You have to submit the request to them and they will do it at some point. They probably are getting hundreds of requests all the time and only prioritizing popular tokens, though.

Comment: The SHNZ token icon at the top of the page and the links have been updated. I guess at some point they will update the ERC-20 name to SHNZ. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

To Verified your ERC-Token and update details you need to contact team of etherscan

[image]

or you can ask to listing in etherscan by Fill in the form: [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe9t2VBwje7zO_xMKT3bO92H8nrzsQJCu2KeFU3PLgAjRONLA/viewform)